# Facebook Audience Network Mediation with admob : We haven't received a bid request

Tags: android, admob, mobile-ad-mediation, facebook-business-sdk

Facebook Audience Network Mediation with admob : We haven't received a bid request
[image: Integration was successfull]

[image: But still showing error]

[image: Admob also showing warning at waterfall source]

Answer (score 2):

Remove facebook audience network (meta) from the waterfall, Facebook stopped waterfall request. Then wait 24 hours to 72 hours. Your app will go to LIVE.
[image]

> I answered this question with my experience.

All the best