# Adapter not found in Facebook Mediation , How can I solve this issue?

Tags: android-studio, admob, mobile-ad-mediation, facebook-ads

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FrrL.png)

I am trying to integrate facebook ads via google admob mediation but its showing adapter not found error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you, after some testing, if you pass the ads in "Biding" and not in "Waterfall" it should work. For me it works anyway.

And remove "Facebook Audience Network" like this post:
[Facebook Audience Network Mediation with admob : We haven't received a bid request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71209661/facebook-audience-network-mediation-with-admob-we-havent-received-a-bid-reque)

I hope this will help you.